# strategy for syncing Android app database with a remote API

Tags: android, database-design, architecture

I'm developing an Android app that is a client to a remote JSON webservice API (I built the server so I have maximum flexibility).

I'm trying to decide what is a good strategy (in terms of battery life, bandwidth and wait times) to keep a local SQLite database synced with the remote API.

what I'm currently thinking is that the server will notify the Android app via GCM about any action (either new data that should be fetched or old data that should be updated),
also, the user will have a refresh button to manually do the sync.

cons of this approach is that if the GCM message is "lost" there is no way to know about any updates or new data.

I can add timestamps and check for new data whenever the user asks to view something but this doesn't solve the way to determine when older data that's already in the SQLite database need to be refreshed.

any suggestions for improving this syncing strategy or any other approaches I should look into ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the app send a received acknowledgement to the server when it gets the GCM push.  Then, if the server doesn't see an acknowledgement in X timeframe, it could resend the GCM push.

Comment: what if I want to use GCM only as an additional feature to keep the data updated when a user opens the app and not as the main syncing mechanism ?

Comment: Then don't use it as the main syncing mechanism...  I guess I don't get your question.