# How many way to sync data between android app and server?

Tags: android

I am planning to an android application and I want to synchronize data between that app and server at the first step after user installed the app to make a contact list.

I just want to know how many way to do it and understand how it work. I searched google but I am not really understand what they are and what they do. I know nothing about android and I'm building my first app.

Looking for ward for your answers.

Thank you.

Comment: you can see here [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829371/sync-data-between-android-app-and-webserver
it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following so is really helpful, please have a look - [Sync data between Android App and webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829371/sync-data-between-android-app-and-webserver)

You can also use Android sync adapter - [Transferring Data Using Sync Adapters](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)

Comment: I take a look all of these but I don't know what is the difference and what is the best way. And how about Cloud?

Comment: What have you find on the links?

Comment: Oh sorry, there is it http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/index.html and I found out one more http://android.appstorm.net/how-to/synchronization/how-to-sync-app-data-across-android-devices-2/