# How to synchronize data between an account and a web server in android?

Tags: android, sql-server-2005, synchronization, account, android-syncadapter

### How to synchronize data between an account and a web server in android?

I have created a project where I am trying to create an account of my own and through that account I want to get the server data after a specific amount of interval period. So far, I have googled, I have found this [useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829371/sync-data-between-android-app-and-webserver)

which tells me a lot. But I can't have a clear idea of the steps what to do for my project. I will certainly appreciate any help or suggestions. Here is what I have done to create my account:-

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
//              startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT));
                str1 = ed1.getText().toString();
                str2 = ed2.getText().toString();
                if ((str1.matches(""))||(!str1.contains("@myapp.com"))) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid type of User email id!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (str2.matches("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                Account account = new Account(str1, "com.example.accountMy");
                String password = str2;
                AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
                boolean success = accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null);
                if(success){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Myapp Account Created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Account is not Created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }});
```

and I have used Customauthenticator and AcountauthenticatorService class to authenticate my account. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

To sync with server you need to extend the `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter` class and override the `onPerformSync` method. It this method you should get the data from the server and insert into your content provider. check [this link](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/) for complete code.

Comment: Thanks bill gates. I am looking into your advised link and certainly going to mark it right if I pass. Please, help me with some more details if you can. Thanks again.