# Angularjs/Ionic SyncAdapter equivalent

Tags: angularjs, synchronization, ionic-framework

Based on this question [Sync data between Android App and webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829371/sync-data-between-android-app-and-webserver), I would like to know if there is an existing javascript (not native) SyncAdapter for an Ionic app (just angular is also ok). If not I would like to get some guidelines to write one in the following aspects:

- How to maintain coherence between app data and server data
- How to manage app offline situation
- Recommended interval to refresh from server
- Battery saving management

Comment: Have yo looked into Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/) and Angular Fire? (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/index.html)

Comment: Not bad. This is a client side library, so the data is in FireBase servers. But this is a paid system which is different from the SyncAdapter that I'm looking for, as it can't synchronize with any server.

Comment: @David, ever find anything that suits your need?  PouchDb would work, if I had a server running couchdb. :(

Comment: @you786 not at all in an already developed solution. For now I'm using angular.js handmade [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) with scheduled timer to check every minute for new data in server.

Comment: I'm wondering how did you solve this issue, if so.