# How do I store a list of data from server for sync adapter if the the list consist of many different items?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-syncadapter

I would like to create a list in an Activity which will retrieve its data from the server. I would like my app to synchonize the data in the list with the server. The tutorial from [google](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) is good enough if every items in the list have the same structure. I can store it just fine in SQLite. I saw a good explanation regarding sync adapter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829371/sync-data-between-android-app-and-webserver). But, what if my list contains many different structures. It's difficult to represent it as a record with the same schema in SQLite. Store it in different tables is really challenging to do in Android. Is there a way to do that? Should I use another database for this case, NoSQL maybe?

Comment: Dont use database. I would recommed you to create the response as a JSON String and store it in SharedPreference

Comment: I've thought of it once. Is it the best way to do it? Actually I am curious how facebook store its news feed. They use sync adapter and their news feed contains many different structures, such as text, image, video, ads, etc.

Comment: Do you have image or the image URL?

Comment: I would recommend you to change the server to provide the URL itself and load the image asynchronously. The reason is if you get all the data and the image along with the response your server call will take lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the format you save the response, I suggest you to save response as json string format, when you want to use the object, just retrieve the json string and parse to object.

Comment: that means I need to give information to the json which structure it belongs to, to parse it to the correct object?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer all your questions by addressing the larger question: How can I sync data between a webserver and an android app?

Syncing data between your webserver and an android app requires a couple of different components on your android device.

Persistent Storage:

This is how your phone actually stores the data it receives from the webserver. One possible method for accomplishing this is writing your own custom ContentProvider backed by a Sqlite database. A decent tutorial for a content provider can be found here: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/writing-your-own-contentprovider/

A ContentProvider defines a consistent interface to interact with your stored data. It could also allow other applications to interact with your data if you wanted. Behind your ContentProvider could be a Sqlite database, a Cache, or any arbitrary storage mechanism.

While I would certainly recommend using a ContentProvider with a Sqlite database you could use any java based storage mechanism you wanted.

Data Interchange Format:

This is the format you use to send the data between your webserver and your android app. The two most popular formats these days are XML and JSON. When choosing your format, you should think about what sort of serialization libraries are available. I know off-hand that there's a fantastic library for json serialization called gson: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/, although I'm sure similar libraries exist for XML.

Synchronization Service

You'll want some sort of asynchronous task which can get new data from your server and refresh the mobile content to reflect the content of the server. You'll also want to notify the server whenever you make local changes to content and want to reflect those changes. Android provides the SyncAdapter pattern as a way to easily solve this pattern. You'll need to register user accounts, and then Android will perform lots of magic for you, and allow you to automatically sync. Here's a good tutorial: http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/

As for how you identify if the records are the same, typically you'll create items with a unique id which you store both on the android device and the server. You can use that to make sure you're referring to the same reference. Furthermore, you can store column attributes like "updated_at" to make sure that you're always getting the freshest data, or you don't accidentally write over newly written data.

Hope this helps.