# Android Sync data to webserver

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter, data-sharing

I have lot of data stored in local DB and I would like implement Backup data feature. As of now I have implemented a service with Alarm that runs on particular time everyday but this works sometimes. I am using retrofit to send data to my server. And alarm to trigger the service on a required time.

Is there a better way? I believe Android Sync does the same job. How does this work? The Google developer doesn't show much on this. I also installed their project couldn't take it further on my project?

Can somebody help me with the best process? and few example would help me a lot!

Thanks!

Comment: read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829371/sync-data-between-android-app-and-webserver

Comment: @pskink: I am running the code that is on developer website. I understand logic of Android Sync in theory but when I execute their project. I couldn't find when the sync is happening? According to project the sync happens every 1 hour. I changed to every minute. I see it is not getting called at all. The onPerformSync is called only when I press refresh button manually.. I am totally confused.

Comment: @HtmlTosin : Please check comment above. Thanks!

Comment: do you have networrk connection up and running?

Comment: @pskink: Yep. It is running. Checked all that.

Comment: INTERNET permission?

Comment: Yep. given.. This is the developer App. So all permission are given. I am able access the URL data.