# Android news feed

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I need to display some data from the server via my `RecyclerView`. The problem is how to notify the application that new data is available in the server.  I have seen in some applications where the top of the list has a button with text like "Show 5 new posts."  After clicking on that button, the 5 new posts download from the server without downloading the entire list of data.  How can I implement that same synchronization?

Comment: Might not be what you want, but also have a look at [Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2J6spwAVP0M) when you have te time.

Comment: @Mikel, server uses MySQL DB :(

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to achieve synchronisation in android.

> 1. You can use SyncAdapter (Highly recommended).
> 2. You can use GCM, push to client if anything new comes up and act accordingly.

Further you can use Local Broadcast Listener to notify that view

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will help you to understand the synchronization between android app and server - [Sync data between Android App and webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829371/sync-data-between-android-app-and-webserver) .